# How can I check if a directory is empty?

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm aware that expect is tcl-in-sheep's-clothing, but even when I google with that in mind I'm coming up empty.

Is there a way to determine if a particular directory is empty (or not empty, I can just use negation)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `glob`, try searching for the pattern `*` in it.

```
set dir "/home/dinesh/stack"
set file_list [glob -nocomplain "$dir/*"]
if {[llength $file_list] != 0} {
    puts "$dir is not empty"
} else {
    puts "$dir is empty"
}
```

Comment: be aware of hidden files

Comment: If I do   if{$file_list==0} it is not triggering. There are no hidden files in this directory. $file_list seems to consist of an empty string, no spaces. Nevermind, just saw the edit.

Comment: to add hidden files, please use this code set itemlist [
    concat [
        glob -nocomplain -dir $dir -types hidden *] [
        glob -nocomplain -dir $dir *]]

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
[glob -nocomplain -dir $dir *]
```

instead of

```
[glob -nocomplain "$dir/*"]
```

If you don't specify the directory in some cases your command will fail (like my Windows 8.1 with Tcl8.6). Specifying the directory the command works fine in Windows and Linux.